# Nuxt3 + Laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How can I get data from api when backend is secured by laravel sanctum?

when I use `useFetch` I do not get any data.

`const {data: cat} = await useFetch('/api/categories')`

Laravel docs told to use axios but in nuxt3 axios module not working.
Can someone help?

I was try use `useFetch` with method get to get csrf cookie but it's doesn't work

```
const {data} = await useFetch('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {method: 'get'}).then(Response => {
    
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I am working on simple package enabling easy integration of laravel sanctum with nuxt3. Maybe it can help you until official auth module for nuxt3 is released.

https://github.com/dystcz/nuxt-sanctum-auth

Answer (score 1):

To get data when using sanctum,

You are already getting the csrf token above by going to the route /sanctum/csrf-cookie.

However, that is not enough.

For every request that you want to make which is secured, you need to send a token that is generated using sanctum.

Usually, for an app, you would follow these steps

1. Login user then generate a sanctum token using

```
$user->createToken('TokenName');
```

2. Once token is generated, you can save this token using cookies on your application. Every time you make a subsequent request to your app, simply send the token along with your request headers as a Bearer Token.
   The header would be something like this

```
"Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN_VALUE;
```

All depends how you are sending the request.

More documentation is available [On this link on Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#issuing-mobile-api-tokens)

Also, ensure you have

```
Accept: Application/json
```

As part of your headers as well.

If you do not send that token in your headers, your requests will give you an error "Unauthenticated".

Below is an example of what I send to the API

[image: Headers sent to API in Postman]

And for Authorization, select the option of Bearer Token

[image: Selecting Bearer Token in Postman]

Hope this helps.

Comment: my friend set everything in the backend and said it was ok. I just have a problem downloading the token. `axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie',{headers:{Accept: "Application/json"}}).then(response => { console.log(response)});` and i have 204 status

Comment: Can you also clear your routes on Laravel. php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` does not return content in the body of the response, that's why you get `HTTP 204 No Content`, during this request Laravel Sanctum will set an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie containing the current CSRF token, you have two ways to use the token: it can be passed via `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header from your requests, or from the original `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

Here's an exemple using the XSRF-TOKEN cookie:

```js
// the browser load the XSRF-TOKEN cookie
await fetch("https://myapi.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});

// now the browser can send a POST request
await fetch("https://myapi.com/api/register", {
  "method": "POST",
  "body": JSON.stringfy({name: 'Joe': email: 'joe@gmail.com'})
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the useFetch or the $fetch doen't return or allow access to the xsrf-cookie. So instead try using axios which automatically appends the xsrf-cookie return from /sanctum/csrf-cookie/ call. To use axios on nuxt3 app you need to create a custom plugin for the axios module.

Here is a link https://www.the-koi.com/projects/nuxt-3-how-to-use-axios/ to direct you. It works perfectly for me as it appends the xsrf header return by  /sanctum/csrf-cookie/ and uses it for subsequent API calls